# Difficulty serializing immutable.Map with spray-json

Tags: scala, spray-json

Apologies in advance for cross-posting: I submitted this question to the spray user list, but the list appears to be moderated, and nobody seems to be home.  Hopefully SO is a better venue.

I am having difficulty serializing complex data structures with `spray-json`.  For example, a simple `immutable.Map[String,String]` works fine, but an `immutable.Map[String,Foo]`, where `Foo` is a case class that I define does not.  The documentation left me with the impression that I simply needed to define a `JsonFormat` for `Foo` and I'd be ready to roll.

Here's some sample code:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

case class Foo(hi: String)

object FooProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val fooFormat: JsonFormat[Foo] = jsonFormat1(Foo)
}
import FooProtocol._

object Thing {
  def toSomething = {
    Map("foo" -> Foo("bar"), "baz" -> Foo("quux")).toJson
  }
}
```

Which yields the following compiler error:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\spraytest\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[error] C:\spraytest\src\main\scala\Foo.scala:12: Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Foo]
[error]     Map("foo" -> Foo("bar"), "baz" -> Foo("quux")).toJson
[error]                                                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Jun 26, 2014 11:40:26 AM
```

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename your `FooProtocol` into `Foo` (this will make it a companion object ~> implicit scope for free) and instead inheritance simply `import DefaultJsonProtocol._`, e.g:

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
case class Foo(hi: String)
object Foo {
  implicit val fooJson = jsonFormat1(Foo.apply)
}
```

Now you need to import correct marshallers into the scope with your Spray route. Marshaller for String can be found in spray DefaultJsonProtocol and Foos marshaller is avail from its companion object, so the only thing you need to import is `spray.httpx.SprayJsonSupport`, that should do the trick.

Or you can leave it as you have it and just `import FooProtocol`. But this is not the best solution from the design point of view.

**Update**

If you take a look at toJson signature, you'll see that it requesters an implicit JsonWriter, which is generated by the jsonFormat method. Companion object solves the trick because scala compiler includes it into the implicit resolution scope, that's a good practice to place your implicates there, cause in this cause you don't need to make explicit import, like `import FooProtocol._`

As for Map and String marshallers, take a look at DefaultJsonProtocol trait, it extends `BasicFormats` and `CollectionFormats`, which has marshallers for String and Map respectively. The only thing you need to add is your own marshaller for `Foo` class.

**Solution**

The real problem was in multiple marshaller implicits in scope. All standard implicits (in this case for Map and String) can be accessed with the single import of `DefaultJsonProtocol`. When you are extending from this trait and then importing it into current scope it also imports all standard marshallers. So the problem was that you had multiple marshallers in scope which caused a problem with ambiguous implicits for scala compiler.

Comment: Your companion object trick solves the problem, but I am at a loss to explain why this is the case. BTW, I am only using `spray-json`, not the whole Spray suite, so `spray.httpx` is not available.

Comment: @DanBarowy i've added my comment to the answer

Comment: I added an inadvertently-missing `import FooProtocol._` to my original question.  This import may be ugly, but if what you say is true, then adding that import should have been sufficient to make the code compile.  Right?  The compiler error in my example seems to imply that Scala can't find an implicit for `Map`, not for `Foo`.  I don't understand how the companion refactoring solves *that* problem.

Comment: @DanBarowy your FooProtocol extends DJP. When you import it into the scope Scala compiler sees multiple map marshallers, this leads to ambiguity in implicit resolution mechanism and Scala can't choose correct marshaler for map and string

Comment: @Alexlv the issue with having both `DefaultJsonProtocol` and `FooProtocol` in scope turns out to be the real answer.  If you update your answer with your comment about ambiguity (for the benefit of future readers), I will happily award points to you.  Thanks!

Comment: @DanBarowy glad that it helped you. I've updated my answer with the actual solution

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no default marshalling for `Map[String,_]`. You can either try to convert your objects toString explicitly (`Map[String,String]` can be serialized to Json) or to provide marshaller for `Map[String, Foo]`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create an object to hold the map, then you can serialize that object.

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

case class Foo(hi: String)

case class Bar( something: Map[String,Foo])

object FooBarProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val fooFormat: JsonFormat[Foo] = jsonFormat1(Foo)
  implicit val barFormat: JsonFormat[Bar] = jsonFormat1(Bar)
}

object Thing {
  def toSomething = {
    Bar(Map("foo" -> Foo("bar"), "baz" -> Foo("quux"))).toJson
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no point in making additional data object (Bar in your case), everything would work with plain Map[String, Foo]

Comment: Your example works after you add `import FooBarProtocol._`.  But I'm still puzzled.  If `DefaultJsonProtocol` has serializers for `Map` and `String` and I provide the one for `Foo`, why do I need to wrap the object? Shouldn't there be an implicit already in scope?